# How do you add specific hyperlinks to highcharts line charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For example, in this demo : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax, when you click on the points, you get a popup with information. Looking at the code though, it appears to be a function for every single point.

How does one go about adding click functions that link to another page to each separate point? For example, the points in the example are split by month. I want to be able to click on a month and get to say, the Wikipedia page for said month.

I have basically no experience in JavaScript or well truthfully, anything related to web design, so apologies if this is trivial!

Thanks!

Comment: You need to click on xAxis label or point datalabel?

Answer (score 2):

In order to open a specific link for a specific point, you have to provide some information in the point object in the data itself.

You can either provide the full url, if each point will open a completely different page, or you can include a unique indentifier that the page will then use to display the specific content.

Then you set the event handler in the plotOptions:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
                cursor:'pointer',
                point:{
                    events:{
                        click:function() {
                            var href = 'http://www.google.com?q=' + this.options.q;
                            window.open(href);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

In this example, I provide a base url in the event handler, and pull the query parameter out of the point object for each individual point.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/8YRq9/

Answer (score 0):

unneeded coded commented, redirect to a new page is inserted right after it.

```
$(function () {

    // Get the CSV and create the chart
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=analytics.csv&callback=?', function (csv) {

        $('#container').highcharts({

            data: {
                csv: csv,
                // Parse the American date format used by Google
                parseDate: function (s) {
                    var match = s.match(/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2})$/);
                    if (match) {
                        return Date.UTC(+('20' + match[3]), match[1] - 1, +match[2]);
                    }
                }
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Daily visits at www.highcharts.com'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                tickWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: -3
                }
            },

            yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: 16,
                    format: '{value:.,0f}'
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
            }, { // right y axis
                linkedTo: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite: true,
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3,
                    y: 16,
                    format: '{value:.,0f}'
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
            }],

            legend: {
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (e) {
                                // hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                //     pageOrigin: {
                                //         x: e.pageX,
                                //         y: e.pageY
                                //     },
                                //     headingText: this.series.name,
                                //     maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
                                //         this.y +' visits',
                                //     width: 200
                                // });
                                window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'All visits',
                lineWidth: 4,
                marker: {
                    radius: 4
                }
            }, {
                name: 'New visitors'
            }]
        });
    });

});
```